# How to send message to facebook using ASP.NET 3.5 and C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, facebook

How to send messages to facebook users using ASP.NET? I need to send messages and images to the Users. I have the Email Id and user authentication keys also if needed. Please try to give some code snippet to implement this one.

Comment: Have you attempted to do anything on this?

Comment: not at.. if you  had any sample snippet please send me. i hanged here.iam very urgent need please try to hellp me

Answer (score 2):

Using the Facebook C# SDK (http://facebooksdk.codeplex.com)

```
var app = new FacebookApp("access_token");
var parameters = new Dictionary<string, object>();
parameters["message"] = "This is a test message";
app.Api("/me", parameters, HttpMethod.Post);
```

That will post a message to the current user's wall. You can also post images using that SDK. There are samples in the tests on how to do that. Note, if you meant that you wanted to sent them a private message rather than post on their wall that is not possible. Facebook does not allow applications to send messages directly to users.